# What does the CONFIG_NLS_UTF8 kernel option do?

Tags: filesystems, kernel, configuration

The kernel configuration contains an `NLS_UTF8` option. It can be found under *File systems → Native language support*. What does it do?

Its description maintains that it is needed for using a FAT or JOLIET CD-ROM filesystem. Is it necessary for an ext[234] filesystem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FAT filenames (not file contents) are encoded in a country-specific manner, DOS called those "codepages". They need to be present in the kernel so your console con correctly display the characters.

This also counts for the UTF-8 encoding of the Unicode charater set.

This doesn't apply to ext FS though, read up [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2089/what-charset-encoding-is-used-for-filenames-and-paths-on-linux).